# Salesforce Login Page not coming for OAuth using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, dialogflow-es, jsforce

I'm trying to login to Salesforce from Google Assistant (using dialogflow) using OAuth. Whatever I say to Google Assistant is supposed to be fulfilled (matched to intent which is then gets matched to the code that fulfills the intent of the user. So, basically the fulfillment code resides on a server (node js express) hosted on Heroku.

The problem is whenever I start by saying 'Talk to test app' I expect to see the Salesforce login page coming up (where I would enter the creds and then the consent part comes) but this page never comes. I'm sure that there might be something missing on my configuration of account linking / code but i'm not able to understand it.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsforce = require('jsforce');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const {
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Image,
  Suggestions,
  Button
 } = require('actions-on-google');

 var options;
 var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

 const expApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());

 //app instance
 const app = dialogflow({
   debug: true
 });

 app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {

 expApp.get('/oauth2/auth', function(req, res) {
  const oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
  clientId: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_KEY,
  clientSecret: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
 });
  res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl({}));
});

//
// Pass received authorization code and get access token
//
expApp.get('/getAccessToken', function(req,res) {
   const oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
   clientId: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_KEY,
   clientSecret: process.env.SALESFORCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
   redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
});

const conn = new jsforce.Connection({ oauth2 : oauth2 });
conn.authorize(req.query.code, function(err, userInfo) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    const conn2 = new jsforce.Connection({
      instanceUrl : conn.instanceUrl,
      accessToken : conn.accessToken
    });
    conn2.identity(function(err, res) {
      if (err) { return console.error(err); }
      console.log("user ID: " + res.user_id);
      console.log("organization ID: " + res.organization_id);
      console.log("username: " + res.username);
      console.log("display name: " + res.display_name);
      options = { Authorization: 'Bearer '+conn.accessToken};
      });
   });
  });

conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
  speech:'Hi, how is it going? You are being guided to the login page',
   text:'Hi, how is it going? You are being guided to the login page',
  }));
});

expApp.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

expApp.listen(port, function () {
  expApp.post('/fulfillment', app);
  console.log('Example app listening on port !');
});
```

[image: Account Linking Settings on Google Actions]

Answer (score 1):

OAuth with Google Assistant is managed from the Actions on Google project that you create for your assistant. In these settings you manage which Token and OAuth URL have to be used for the sign-in in your app. If you want the users to sign-in through the assistant app, you will have to choose the [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2#implement_oauth_account_linking) sign-in option.

So you don't have to use your own code to get the OAuth page, you can just use the [SignIn()](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2#start_the_authentication_flow) response given to you in the Actions on Google SDK. This will trigger the account linking flow for Google Assistant.

```
app.intent('Start Signin', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
});

app.intent('ask_for_sign_in_confirmation', (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
    return conv.ask('You need to sign in before using the app.');
  }
  // const access = conv.user.access.token;
  // possibly do something with access token
  return conv.ask('Great! Thanks for signing in.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jordi! First of all, what I want is the standard Salesforce login page to come when user says 'Talk to test app'  . This is required since the user has to be in Salesforce and it is through his user I would perform actions on Salesforce and hence I would like to authenticate and authorize him. On reading about the actions.intent.SignIn  intent I understood that to initiate account linking  I need to add this on my code but as far I understand I would still need my custom code to also get Salesforce login page by using the oauth class of jsForce.

Comment: The Authorization URL that you set in your Google Assistant project functions as the URL to your sign-in page. So if you set that in your settings and call SignIn() it should attempt to open the URL on a connected mobile device. One thing you should know, if you start your action with a sign-in prompt, Google will not promote your action, so it is a good practice to create a guest flow and only prompt the user with the sign-in when it is absolutely necessary. https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2?oauth=code#start_the_authentication_flow

Comment: You will still need to create an OAuth login page using the salesforce OAuth methods. But this is outside what you do with the code for the Assistant.

Comment: Yes , so my fulfillment server is on node js express and is hosted on Heroku. I did give url of the same on Authorization URL and created routes on express for redirecting to Salesforce login page and then once user gives consent get the Access Token (this is another route on express). Now, these routes are present after conv.ask(new SignIn) on welcome intent handler. When I start speaking to Google, I am now shown the message for account linking and after my consent it redirects to the URL (Express app) however it stops there and doesn't take me to the login page.

Comment: Which "login page" in this case? (You may want to update your question to show how you have things configured in the Action console, masking out sensitive parts of the URL, and laying out exactly what is and isn't happening at this point.)

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the settings done in Acccount Linking on Google Actions.Right now, after the usual account linking message from Google and then after my consent redirection to the Express App page is happening . I would actually need to show the Salesforce Login Page instead where they would put in their credentials and see the Allow / Deny page (this whole process as I understand has to be done by setting up routes on express).